# Rails 6 with devise JWT auth, can you have different expiration times by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

I'm currently using devise, devise_ldap_authenticatable, and devise-jwt.

I have a default expiration time of 1 day.

That is fine for interactive users. However the App serves mostly as an API therefore I want to allow an account or accounts the ability to use their Bearer token for an extended period of time.

They should be able to use automation on their end to interact with the API and not have to log in manually every day to get their new token.

Is it possible to flex the expire time or another method to allow certain users tokens to not expire? This isn't internet facing. Its internal, using LDAP accounts, however I'd like to allow LDAP service accounts to have long/longer term tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set different JWT expiration time for interactive users and users that use automations.
You can monkey-patch a method in the `devise-jwt` library where this token is set. Or go directly to `warden-jwt_auth` and monkey-patch method here: https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/warden-jwt_auth/blob/master/lib/warden/jwt_auth/token_encoder.rb